# Logging in the separate thread in Node.js with Winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, logging, winston

Is it possible to delegate logging to separate thread in NodeJS using Winston out of the box?

I want to minimize blocking operations and other side affects for performance.

And I think about moving logging to the separate thread.

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const { Worker, isMainThread,  workerData } = require('worker_threads');

class MyLogger
{
    info(message) {
        if (isMainThread) {
            this.thread = new Worker(__filename)
        } else {
            this.getLoggerInstance().info(message);
        }
    }

    getLoggerInstance() {
        if (! this.logger) {
            this.logger = winston.createLogger({
                level: 'info',
                format: winston.format.json(),
                defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
                transports: [
                    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
                    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
                ]
            });
        }
        return this.logger;
    }
}


// USAGE
const myLogger = new MyLogger();

myLogger.info('something I want to log');
```

Does anyone tries to do the same?

Do you know any limitations?

Will it help for performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It delegates saving to file to a separate thread while still using Winston in the main one

```
const winston = require('winston');
const {Worker, isMainThread, parentPort} = require('worker_threads');
const Transport = require("winston-transport");

const LOG = "LOG"
let thread;

class WorkerTransport extends Transport {
    constructor(opts) {
        super(opts);
    }

    log(info, callback) {
        thread && thread.postMessage({type: LOG, data: info})
        callback();
    }
}

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: {service: 'user-service'},
});


if (isMainThread) {
    thread = new Worker(__filename);
    logger.add(new WorkerTransport({}));
} else {
    logger.add(new winston.transports.File({filename: 'error.log', level: 'error'}));
    logger.add(new winston.transports.File({filename: 'combined.log'}));

    parentPort.on("message", ({type, data}) => {
        switch (type) {
            case LOG: {
                logger.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
}

//Example usage
logger.info('something I want to log. Main thread = ' + isMainThread);

module.exports = logger;
```